# specify directory or path using slash or dot slash

Tags: javascript, node.js

in a node tutorial, the author use this `var require = require('./something');`

I wonder why it's not `require('../something')`, which goes up one level and find something

Comment: My guess is the plugin is in the same directory...

Comment: The psuedo-code logic of how `require` resolves paths: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a directory tree such as

```
root
  dir
     file1
     file2
  dir2
     file1
     file2
```

If you are in `root/dir`  `.`  refers to `root/dir` so `./file1` refers to `/root/dir/file1`. `..` refers to `root` so `../file1` doesn't exist (`root/file1`)

Answer (score 3):

`.` represent the current working directory

`..` represent the parent directory of the current working directory.

So, if we use `require('./something')`, that means we want to find `something` in the current directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a relative redirect:

'../' == one level up 
'/path' == relative to domain

Directory Separator = / 
Current Directory = . 
Parent Directory = .. 
Home Directory = ~

Comment: I think, avoid using \ character. It may also work but its not recommended as it can act as escape character. [Escape Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)
eg: C:\file may be interpreted as C:ile